# How to bind a html doc to display records from a sql server database?

Tags: .net, sql, html, winforms

I have a winform application that will use html to display a field from sql server database. 1 how to bind the html doc to the the database. 2 how then display a field called Company for example. 3 what component would you suggest to use to display the html doc. This program is written in C# and I have limited programming in html.

Comment: If you're new, be sure to look at .net MVC, it is way easier than traditional .net development.

Comment: I'll look at that but this is a winform project not asp

Comment: I think we may need more details, so your winform app needs to display embedded html? Like  using the [webbrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: If we need to embed a browser control that will display a html doc that is fine. The problem is then we need to create a html doc that will display info from the SQL server database. We could do this in Delphi using pageprovider and dataprovider but am unsure how to link the html to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a webpage that pulls data from database then you need server side scripting language, you create the html the way you want it to look, and that's it. Html is a markup language for display purposes, on it's own, there is no way it can pull data from a database nor be linked to a database at all. You can embed some javascript on it so that the javascript consumes some web service and updates the page maybe.

Comment: <div style="display:none">
<OBJECT classid="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83"
    ID=tdcComposer HEIGHT=0 WIDTH=0>
 <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="/workshop/samples/author/databind/composer.csv">
 <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="True">
    <PARAM NAME="TextQualifier" VALUE="'">
</OBJECT>
I have found this code and it shows how to bind with a csv file I need to do something similar but with a SQL Database.

Comment: Yes, but the csv file is a static resource that you can access like any text file. Directly binding to a database it's another thing that cannot be done with just html. Even if you somehow expose your database so it can be consumed as a resource (maybe as a RESTful service), I don't think it's a good idea for security reasons.  Maybe you can create an ashx handler, that you can access with the same code you have there, that will return the csv data (created from data in the database).

Comment: If I can't bind is there a windows control that can handle the connection between the database and the html. The reason we want to use the html is if we want to make a style change we can just upload a css file instead of recompiling the whole program.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. What component did you end up using?

Comment: I believe, if this needs can not be a web app, you may need something that can use some sort of styling that you can fix only in one place. I know Silverlight or flash allow you to setup something like this. But I believe if you want html and css, you may need to research a bit into creating some web services server side, and consuming them with javascript.